# SQL - IN clause with no match

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to build a query where I can select from a table all products with a certain ID but I would also like to find out what products were not found within the IN clause.

**Product Table**

```
ID | Name
---|---------
1  | ProductA
2  | ProductB
4  | ProductD
5  | ProductE
6  | ProductF
7  | ProductG
```

```sql
select *
from products
where id in (2,3,7);
```

As you can see, product id 3 does not exist in the table.
My query will only return rows 2 and 7.
I would like a blank/null row returned if a value in the IN clause did not return anything.

***Desired Results:***

```
ID | Name
---|---------
2  | ProductB
3  | null
7  | ProductG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN is not useful in this case.
Use a CTE with the ids that you want to search for and left join to the table:

```
with cte(id) as (select * from (values (2),(3),(7)))
select c.id, p.name 
from cte c left join products p
on p.id = c.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ca198FEDsDxxrR1QwXqEnG/0).
Results:

```
| id  | Name     |
| --- | -------- |
| 2   | ProductB |
| 3   |          |
| 7   | ProductG |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select i.id, p.name
from (select 2 as id union all select 3 union all select 7
     ) i left join
     products p
     on p.id = i.id
```

Comment: This answer also provides the desired results. Thank you.